# jquery slideDown rather than slideAndPush

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, slidedown

I have a div where I click on a link to slideDown. As expected it does what it promises however, I prefer it to slide open without pushing the other elements down as well. so like a layer on top of other layers. is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but not entirely simple. I've done it before [here (the video hover-overs)](http://nidostudentliving.com/london/kings-cross/home.php).

The concept basically goes:

1. Set position relative on your current element (the one you're floating, or its parent if that makes more sense). This can be statically set in your CSS.
2. Create a new element, style it similarly with the same dimensions and position it right above your current element using `position:absolute` and `z-index:...`
3. use slideDown (or alter the height, again, depending on what makes most sense) and it should be above the rest of your content

Comment: I've actually done it several times on that page. I used a similar technique for the slide selector and the menu uses a reverse version.

Answer (score -1):

Try floating your elements. If they are div's they should slide over one another.